# DATE_ADD() on select() with codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I'm wondering how I could use mysql `DATE_ADD()` in codeigniter `SELECT` .

EDIT: ... `DATE_ADD()` and basically any other MySQL Function within `SELECT` .

This is what I have. Also tried putting `FALSE` as second parameter.

```
$this->db->select(" DATE_ADD( purchased_on , INTERVAL 1 YEAR) AS wrty_end");
```

The result is that it reads `INTERVAL` as a field. It works fine when I try to run this in phpmyadmin without the backticks enclosing `INTERVAL`.

```
DATE_ADD( purchased_on, `INTERVAL` 1 YEAR) AS wrty_end
```

Answer (score 2):

use second param `FALSE` so it wont add backticks to your fields, like

```
$this->db->select(" DATE_ADD( purchased_on , INTERVAL 1 YEAR) AS wrty_end", FALSE);
```

see:: Codeigniter [select()](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$this->db->select("DATE_ADD( purchased_on , INTERVAL 1 YEAR) AS wrty_end", false)->get('table_name');
```